# Checking if an sql record exists from an aspx.vb web form

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I've been doing a project in visual studio 2010 for about a week. I'm using vb and a simple sql database. I'm attempting to make a login page that checks whether there is a record in the customer table with the specified email and password. I've come to a point where I'm out of my debugging depth, can anyone see whats causing the error?

the Login.aspx.vb file for the Login web form looks like this:

```
Imports LoginTableAdapters

Partial Class Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim LoginAdapter As LoginTableAdapter

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim email As String
    Dim pass As String
    LoginAdapter = New LoginTableAdapter

    email = TextBox1.Text
    pass = TextBox2.Text

    If Me.LoginAdapter.QueryLogin(email, pass) Then
        Label1.Visible = True
    End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

The SQL for QueryLogin() looks like this:

```
SELECT        custemail, custpassword
FROM            customer
WHERE        (custemail = @Param1) AND (custpassword = @Param2)
```

And this is the error that only happens when entering a correct user/pass combination:

```
Server Error in '/DinnerNow' Application.
Input string was not in a correct format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

  <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

Stack Trace:


[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +181
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean(String Value) +147

[InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "test@test.test" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.]
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean(String Value) +337
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean(Object Value) +1304756
   Login.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +104
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553178
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: can i see the parameter declarations in your SQL QueryLogin()? it looks like it's set as boolean for the email from the error message but i need to see the param declaration to be sure.

Comment: You should consider what will happen if I type into the text boxes "a@b.com OR 1=1" and "pwd OR 1=1". Hint: read up on SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv - Do you mean "@Param1" and "@Param2" ? Those aren't declared, they're just blank ready for something to be passed into them. Its what the Query Builder did.

Comment: they aren't declared with data types? like VarChar @Param1... ?

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv no, they are declared right there and thats the only place they exist. I dont really get how they don't have a type but I guess SQL is ok with that

Comment: @DaleM - I read up on injection attacks. Thanks for the heads up. I probably wont worry about security. I need to get it functioning before I do anyhow

Comment: ok... in VS, on this line: Me.LoginAdapter.QueryLogin(... if you delete the rest manually and leave just this: Me.LoginAdapter.QueryLogin ,  and then if you then add that (, intellisense should show you the types of parameters it expects... what does that say?

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv - It wants a String. Also the fields in the SQL table are nvarchar format incase that has something to do with it

Comment: ok well this line: (Line 104) Login.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +104 is trying to convert your email string into a Boolean.

Comment: OK, up to you but it is way easier if you think about it first. I could have put in the second box "pwd); DELETE * FROM customer".

Comment: @DaleM - lol, you would have broken everything. Its a good job I didnt let you near the real thing :P

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv - I just added customerid (the primary key of the table) to the SQL Query, so the SELECT line looks like this: "SELECT        customerid, custemail, custpassword" Thats literally all I changed, based on some good advice I saw in a youtube video and not related to the problem at all. But it totally fixed the problem. Sometimes these error messages are totally misleading. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think Ken below has a point though... you might currently be converting your customerid into a boolean... which is not what you want in the end... check both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is

```
If Me.LoginAdapter.QueryLogin(email, pass)
```

which means value returned to this should be boolean type. But your sql query is returning custemail, custpassword. Which are of string type.  So, boolean can not be compare to string type.

Change your sql to

```
if((SELECT   Count(*) FROM customer WHERE (custemail = @Param1) AND (custpassword = @Param2))>0)
   Select Cast(1 as bit) IsCustomerExist
Else
    Select Cast(0 as bit) IsCustomerExist
```